Semidirect product using a matrix
When I was reading a paper I found a notation that sounds strange to me. The object is a semidirect product $\mathbb{Z}^2 \rtimes_A \mathbb{Z}$ where $A$ denotes a matrix (an Anosov matrix but I don't know if this is relevant).
What means $\rtimes_A$? I mean, how is the operation?

You need a homomorphism from $\Bbb Z $ to $\rm Aut (\Bbb Z^2).$  Can you say more about the matrix?

I reckon $\rm Aut (\Bbb Z^2)$ may be $\rm GL_2(\Bbb Z).$

Let $N,H$ be groups and $\rho: N \to \text{Aut}(H)$ be a group homomorphism. Then one can define the semi-direct product $N \rtimes_\rho H$ with $(n,h)(n',h'):=(n\rho(h)(n'),hh')$.
Here is $\mathbb{Z}^2 = N$ and $\mathbb{Z} = A$. Every homomorphism $\rho: \mathbb{Z} \to \text{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}^2)$ is uniquely determined by the generator $1$ of $\mathbb{Z}$, i.e. $\rho(n) = \rho(1)^n$. Now define $\rho_A(1):=A$. Then $\mathbb{Z}^2 \rtimes_A \mathbb{Z} := \mathbb{Z}^2\rtimes_{\rho_A} \mathbb{Z}$.

Let me see if I got it. We have a homomorphism $\rho$ but since $\rho$ is defined on $\mathbb{Z}$ it is enough to know $\rho(1)$. So, the author just calls $\rho(1) = A$ but he is working with a homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $Aut(\mathbb{Z}^2)$?

So to unfold the definitions a bit, in this case the semi-direct product has underlying set $\mathbb{Z}^2 \times \mathbb{Z}$ and the group operation is defined by $(v, m) (w, n) := (v + A^{n} w, m + n)$.

Yes, abuse of notation.
